# log4j - Is there a feature to provide auto-numbering?

Tags: log4j

I would like to ask if log4j provides auto numbering feature to each log appended?

For example:

```
1 Message test A.
2 Message test B.
3 Message test C.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not out of the box.

You can look at `PatternLayout` class, extend it, and override

```
 protected PatternParser createPatternParser(String pattern);
```

method to create your own `MyPatternParser`, extending `PatternParser` (see the source), overriding the method:

```
protected void finalizeConverter(char c);
```

Come up with a new conversion character and write a new `PatternConverter` to supply an int value, increasing every time it's accessed.

I did something like that for a similar feature, don't have access to that code now, but it's more or less what was needed.

P.S.: Now that you can upvote, you could be so kind to appreciate my previous effort to help you.

Comment: This the easiest part of the solution. How will you guarantee the correct numbering? What if the log file is deleted? What if the application is restarted?

Comment: @KarelFrajtak Man, read the question word for word. Mike's asking if it's achievable in log4j. I believe we're not here to provide a full working solution to anyone, just nudge people in the right direction. Feel free to supply your own answer. That said, your remarks are quite to the point, thank you.

Comment: @KarelFrajtak BTW, I'm not willing to provide extensive and elaborate answers to people that don't care enough to click a damn button in return for someone's time.

Comment: I understand you, I just wanted to point out that creating a pattern parser is solution to only half of the problem (and I changed my mind with down vote;). Your answer might have been more accurate with just saying "to implement the autonumbering feature you need the patter parser and the class that will DO the autonumbering - provide the value"